# Mysql Get rows that are not used yet

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with my query.

I need to select data that is not selected in another query.

So what is mean is:
Table 1 have 50 Questions
Table 2 have selected 32
Then there are 18 not used.
I only need to select that 18 not used questions.

Hope you can help me!

Edit:
Table with all Questions:
Id - InputType - InputName - InputLabel

Table with the selected questions:
Id - required - position

Relations: Id with Id

Comment: What is your table structure ?

Comment: And what is the relation between the tables ?

Comment: Take a look at the EXCEPT statement. Might be what you are looking for. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 T2 ON T1.Id=T2.Id
WHERE T2.required IS NULL
```

**Explanation:**

When we join those tables with `LEFT JOIN`, it will select all records from Table1 and corresponding records from Table2 (if any). And we are excluding the questions which are already in Table2.

Consider the table data:

```
Table1                       Table2
--------------------------------------------------
id    Question               id     Question
1     Question1              1      Question1
2     Question2              3      Question3
3     Question3              5      Question5
4     Question4              
5     Question5              
6     Question6
```

Then this query will result:

```
id    Question   
-----------------                 
2     Question2                 
4     Question4 
6     Question6
```

Comment: Only 1 little problem. He gets now only the question that are selected. so i have to turn it or something like that.

Comment: @MathieuP: It is because you have misplaced the table names. Just change it. Table1 should be the table with full questions. Or you can use `RIGHT JOIN` without changing names. Both will work.

Comment: SELECT formbuildingblock.*
                                FROM formbuildingblock
                                RIGHT JOIN formbbformtemplate
                                ON formbuildingblock.formBuildingBlockId = formbbformtemplate.formBuildingBlockId
                                WHERE formbbformtemplate.formTemplateId = ".$_GET['formTemplateId'].";

Comment: @MathieuP: Which one is the table with complete records?

Comment: I got it. I will place comment with what i have now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    aq.* 
FROM 
all_questions aq
LEFT JOIN selected_questions sq ON sq.Id = aq.Id
WHERE sq.Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

From your statement, it looks like used questions are stored in another table Table2. So it would be something like;

```
Select * From Table1 A
Left Join Table2 B On A.QuestionID = B.QuestionID
Where B.QuestionID is Null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Except`

select those questions in First table but not in Second Table

```
select QuiestionID from Questions
except
select QuiestionID from SelectedQuestions
```

Answer (score 0):

Final answer what i made with all your alswers.

```
SELECT fbb.*
FROM formbuildingblock fbb
LEFT JOIN formbbformtemplate fbbft
ON fbbft.formBuildingBlockId = fbb.formBuildingBlockId
WHERE fbbft.formBuildingBlockId IS NULL;
```